# Passing a public variable to a function in truffle console

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js, truffle

I have a simple function to compare two string:

```
function stringCmp(string a, string b) public returns (bool){ 
  bytes memory aa=bytes(a);
  bytes memory bb=bytes(b);
  if(aa.length!=bb.length)
    return false;
  for(uint i=0; i< aa.length; i++)
    if(aa[i]!=bb[i])
      return false;
  return true;
}
```

This function properly work in truffle console if used as follow:

```
t=contract_name.at("address_of_c");
t.stringCmp.call("string1","string1") --> true
t.stringCmp.call("string1","string2") --> false
```

Supposing we have declared in the contract:

```
string public p="ciao";
string public q="ciao";
string public r="hello";
```

Which is the properly way to pass those string to the call? 
I tried :

```
t=contract_name.at("address_of_c");
t.stringCmp.call(t.p(),t.q()) --> true (and it seems ok but..)
t.stringCmp.call(t.p(),t.r()) --> true (So what..???)
t.stringCmp.call(t.p,t.r) --> true (???)
t.stringCmp.call(t.p.call(),t.q.call()) --> Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function
```

Moreover what is exactly going on? 
Any Workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the console is helping you when you try to execute the commands without handling the promises correctly. Your contract members (p, q, r) when called with web3 will return a promise that's why all returns true (since if you just do `t.p` or `t.r` from the console it will return the same object)

So said the last attempt is the most close one but the `call` function returns a promise and is not handled correctly (but if you try to do just `t.q.call()` from the console it will work, same as `t.q()`; again, the truffle console might help handling the promises itself).

If you handle the promises correctly it will work

```
t.r.call().then((r1) => t.q.call().then((q1) => t.stringCmp(q1, r1).then(console.log)))
```

this return `false`

```
t.p.call().then((p1) => t.q.call().then((q1) => t.stringCmp(q1, p1).then(console.log)))
```

this will return `true`